# converting ascii number to strings in R

Tags: r

To convert strings to ascii code in R, I typically use:

```
> strtoi(charToRaw("abcd"),16L)
[1] 97 98 99 100
```

Is there a function to do the inverse, i.e.

```
>myDesiredFunc(c(97 98 99 100)) 
[1] "abcd"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just noticed that `R` has a `intToUtf8` and `utf8ToInt` functions that does the same thing.

```
> test<-utf8ToInt("Apples")
> test
[1]  65 112 112 108 101 115
> intToUtf8(test)
[1] "Apples"
```

Answer (score 9):

Also:

```
 rawToChar(as.raw(c(97,98,99,100)))
```

Type `?charToRaw` at the command prompt for more info.

Comment: The obvious solution I suppose. :-P

Comment: Hm, how on earth I did not answer that?

Comment: Probably trying to be the first to answer - it's the curse of stackoverflow. Answer too slowly and someone gets in first with almost the exact same response.

Comment: @user3114046, apologies for unchecking your reply as the answer as I found that R already has functions for it. see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Best I found is:

```
readLines(rawConnection(as.raw(c(97,98,99,100,13))))
```

Although I guess it is better to close the connection

```
con = rawConnection(as.raw(c(97,98,99,100,13)))
res = readLines(con);
close(con);
show(res);

[1] "abcd"
```