# Convert an integer to base36

Tags: r, base36

`strtoi(x,base=36)` will convert a base36-encoded string to an integer:

```
strtoi("zzzz",base=36)
[1] 1679615
```

Is there a function that inverts this operation, i.e., given a positive integer yields the base36 equivalent? Essentially, I'm looking for an `itostr()` function such that

```
itostr(1679615,base=36)
[1] "zzzz"
```

(I don't need any base other than 36, but a `base` argument would be nice to have.)

Comment: also https://github.com/statsmaths/baseN

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a similar question is discussed [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123314/converting-ascii-number-to-strings-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe if you install the package *BBmisc*, it has the itostr function is available.

```
library(BBmisc)
itostr(1679615,base=36)
[1] "zzzz"
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any implementations, but the algorithm isn't that difficult.  Here's one that works on 32-bit signed integers.

```
intToBase36 <- function(int) {
  stopifnot(is.integer(int) || int < 0)

  base36 <- c(as.character(0:9),LETTERS)
  result <- character(6)
  i <- 1L
  while (int > 0) {
    result[i] <- base36[int %% 36L + 1L]
    i <- i + 1L
    int <- int %/% 36L
  }
  return(paste(result, sep="", collapse=""))
}
```

You could use the [bit64](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html) and [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) packages if you need to support larger integers.

Comment: Nice. I was a bit taken aback that it broke on `intToBase36(1679615)`, but then again, of course `is.integer(1679615)` is `FALSE`, and a little coercing using `intToBase36(1679615L)` does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

A quick Rcpp hack [of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) will get you it as well:

```
library(inline)

cxxfunction(signature(x="numeric"), body='
unsigned int val = as<unsigned int>(x);
static char const base36[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
std::string result;
result.reserve(14);
do {
  result = base36[val % 36] + result;
} while (val /= 36);
return wrap(result);
', plugin="Rcpp") -> base36enc

base36enc(36)
## [1] "10"

base36enc(72)
## [1] "20"

base36enc(73)
## [1] "21"
```

It definitely needs a bit more code for production use, though.

The `BBmisc` package referenced in another answer is also [C-backed](https://github.com/berndbischl/BBmisc/blob/master/src/itostr.c) so it's probably a good, performant choice.

Comment: #ty Joshua. I have no idea how that happened (and I should have caught it)

Comment: This looks interesting, but to be honest, it's a bit intimidating for me as a non-Rcpp-user. (I assume the canonical rejoinder is that I *should* become an Rcpp user. I plead lack of time.) Plus, I get cryptical errors that may be connected to my German default locale: "include/Rcpp/Date.h:103: error: field â€˜m_tmâ€™ has incomplete type".